# TestNet ETH Disappear after receiving it immediately

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, testnets

Whenever I get any Testnets (Sepolia or Goerli) to my MetaMask  Its Immediately transferred away from my wallet to another address **0x000ED96F3C5636BBB1A4fa59B96C2CCD042e5000** without any of my permission This happened 3 times
[image]

Want to ask How to sort that problem

Comment: This looks like a sweeper bot attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not the one transferring out your ETH, that means someone else has the private key to your account. Create a new account and keep your private key private. Be grateful they're only taking testnet funds